# Make cannot find target with wildcard pattern

Tags: c++, makefile, wildcard, target

```
CXXSRC            = $(shell find source -iname "*.cpp")
CXXSRCFN          = $(notdir $(CXXSRC))
CXXOBJ            = $(CXXSRCFN:%.s=output/obj/%.cpp.o)

OUTPUT            = output/kernel.elf


.PHONY: builduserspace clean all



all: $(OUTPUT)
    @$(QEMU) -vga std -serial file:"output/serialout.log" -m 20 -hda output/disk.img -rtc base=localtime


$(OUTPUT): $(CXXOBJ)
    # Linking object files...
    @$(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o output/temp.elf output/obj/Start.s.o $(shell find output/obj -name "*.o" ! -name "Start.s.o") -Lgcc

    # Performing objcopy...
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O elf32-i386 output/temp.elf output/kernel.elf


%.cpp.o: %.cpp
    @echo $(notdir $<)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(notdir $@) $<
```

That's the makefile. Here's the situation, imagine this directory structure:

```
output
|
|-- obj

source
|
|-- file1.cpp
|-- file2.cpp
|-- subdirectory
    |
    |-- file3.cpp
```

Say I run make in the root folder (where output and source are). The target output is output/kernel.elf.

Essentially, I want all the files in the folder 'source' to be compiled into object files and placed into the folder output/obj.

I managed to get the variables about right; CXXSRC is simply the list of all source files to be compiled; CXXOBJ is the list of outputs.

However, make: *** No rule to make target `output/obj/file.cpp.o', needed by`output/kernel.elf'.  Stop.

After some trial and error, I managed to narrow down the issue: If I modify the target to this:

```
output/obj/%.cpp.o: source/subdirectory/%.cpp
```

It works fine (ie. it errors on the other files in my tree, because not all files are in subdirectory)

Obviously this would defeat the purpose of the % wildcard operator, so how do I fix this problem?

Thanks.
First SO post, take it easy on me (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, you can't.  In a pattern rule the pattern (`%`) must be identical (string-wise) between the target and the prerequisite.  It can't mean "something sort of, but not exactly, the same".

I think it's a bit unpleasant to compile source files from multiple different directories and put the output into a single directory.  Every single time I've seen that done it's become a big problem (because people sometimes use the same source file name and then you have a mess).

If you really want to do it there's no choice but to declare multiple rules with the different source directories.  There are ways to do this in the makefile without writing them all by hand, but they're somewhat more advanced.

Comment: Sigh. I thought it would be something ridiculous like that.

In that case I'll just put the object files in the same place as the source file and do a find to link.
Luckily most modern IDEs know how to hide object files from the directory tree.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's "ridiculous"; how do you think make should intuit that these paths are related, if they don't match?  Anyway, you don't have to put them in the same _directory_, you just have to use the same directory _structure_.  That is, you can put the object for `source/file1.cpp` in `output/obj/file1.cpp.o` and the object for `source/subdirectory/file3.cpp` into `output/obj/subdirectory/file3.cpp.o`; that's simple.  You just can't put both objects directly into the _same_ directory.